# Exchange EAC and EMS not working - HTTP error 503

Tags: exchange

I have installed Exchange 2016 and for some reason when I am accessing the Exchange Management Center I can see the login page but after a successful login, he navigates me to: http://localhost/owa with a white page showing HTTP error 503.

Also when trying to access Exchange Management Shell, the shell throws me an error: "WinRM cannot process the request because the input XML contains a syntax error"

I tried to change the certificate in the binding on 443 and 444 to the "Exchange Server" certificate - didn't work.

But for some reason I have too many certs:
[Link to the Certs in Certificates MMC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFLFT.png)

this is how it looks like in the IIS window:
[Certs in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2O2E.png)

Maybe I need to emove all of them and create a new Certificate?
Note: I DOn't want a "GoDaddy" like cert, because it's only for local purposes

Answer (score 1):

Various factors can lead to this error. To resolve this issue, view the System log in Event Viewer to find if there is any related error.

The possible cause may be missing of SSL certificate of the Exchange Backend Website. To determine, check your event log first.

For your reference, you can read this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2619402/error-503-service-unavailable-when-you-browse-windows-sbs-websites

Comment: Hi, please let me know if the suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Any updates with your issue?